# Is it possible to cast jedit TextArea to java.awt.TextComponent or to javax.swing.JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, casting, textarea, jtextarea

I wonder if it is possible to cast [`org.gjt.sp.jedit.textarea`](http://www.jedit.org/api/org/gjt/sp/jedit/textarea/TextArea.html) to javax.swing.JTextArea or to  java.awt.TextComponent?

Comment: Neither of those are ancestors of the GJT class, so no.

Comment: And what happened when you tried?

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.Object
  java.awt.Component
      java.awt.Container
          javax.swing.JComponent
              org.gjt.sp.jedit.textarea.TextArea
```

So I guess not...

Answer (score 0):

But it is possible to use the jEdit's textarea in a swing application.
ant build-textArea called on jEdit's sources will generate the textarea library that can be embedded.